# EC2 linux user creation with account expiration after defined duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create an EC2 linux user having access for specified duration or after consumption of specified data units after which the user account should expire. How can set the auto expiration for a user account?

The intent is to provide users with individual training account on EC2 linux instance which expire after specified time or after consumption of specified data, to contain cost.

Any help or pointers on this would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

You can control how long a user's account is valid through the use of the **--expiredate** option to **useradd**.

useradd(8) man page

```
-e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
 The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is
 specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

 If not specified, useradd will use the default expiry date specified
 by the EXPIRE variable in /etc/default/useradd, or an empty string 
 (no expiry) by default.
```

You can use this command to specify a date +30 days in the future from now,

```
useradd -e `date -d "30 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"` username
```

to adjust their expiration dates

```
chage -E `date -d "30 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"` username
```